# bash: __vte_prompt_command: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, fedora, gnome-terminal

```
bash: __vte_prompt_command: command not found
```

Whenever I open a terminal, I am greeted with this line. Also, this is printed each time I enter a command in the terminal.

I am a linux-noob, and would be happy to read up, if someone can point me to some resource, or hint at a possible solution. I tried google-ing, but was unable to turn up with any useful results.

I did not do anything specific just before this started popping up.

Thanks in advance :)

**Additional Info:**

- The terminal I used is the default gnome-terminal
- Fedora 20

Comment: can you show your ~/.bashrc content?

Comment: and what does `echo $PS1` show?

Comment: You should also check for file /etc/profile.d/vte.sh which is installed as part of libvte packgage. You probably source this file in your ~/.bashrc script, but vte.sh is missing now and hence your error.

Comment: I restarted the system, and this solved the problem. Unfortunately, I failed to look at `~/.bashrc` before restarting. I will try to reproduce the problem, and will post if I succeed. Thanks @HomayounAfshari and @m.wasowski :)

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like a program named VTE has set your bash environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to invoke a function called `__vte_prompt_command`.

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable defines a command that is executed before every new prompt is displayed to the screen.  It can be *very* annoying when this command produces unexpected output.

You can temporarily get rid of the annoying messages by entering this command in the terminal:

```
__vte_prompt_command() { true; }
```

This creates a dummy function that does nothing - you can confirm by looking at the output of this command:

```
type __vte_prompt_command
```

After applying the hack to my system I see this:

```
__vte_prompt_command is a function
__vte_prompt_command ()
{
    true
}
```

However, this is an indication that VTE may not be installed properly and/or may be broken.  You might want to try to reinstall VTE, if possible.  I would *not* recommend putting this permanently into your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: well this code  ' __vte_prompt_command() { true; } ' solved temporarily for me the problem but I want that it disappears forever and that It can be solved properly . Thanks jn advance

Answer (score 3):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with the default gnome-terminal and ran into the same problem but wanted a definitive solution.

After trying the solutions suggested previously, I still had the message:
`__vte_prompt_command: command not found`
comming up after starting a new terminal and after each command terminated.

I searched for a file in for instance `.bashrc`, `.profile` that would be doing a `source /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh` with no luck.
Than I remembered that a long time ago I added the following line in my `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

in order to append command line histories to all opened terminals. I figured out that commenting it solved the problem.

```sh
#export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

than
`$ source ~/.bashrc`

Thought I would share this for anyone having the same problem.

Comment: Same here, tried to use Tilix, added a line to `.zshrc` and forgot about it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was hitting this issue as well. To diagnose it, I used [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to find files on my system containing `__vte_prompt_command`:

```
> sudo ag -l __vte_prompt_command 2>/dev/null /
```

The first result that turned up was `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh`. Looking into that file, I see an early exit if your terminal isn't named according to its expectations:

```
# TERM not supported?
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|vte*|gnome*) :;;
    *) return 0 ;;
esac
```

In my case, I think here's the explanation:

1. When I open a terminal, `TERM` was set to `xterm-256color`. `vte-2.91.sh` would execute, `__vte_prompt_command` would be defined, and`PROMPT_COMMAND` would be set.
2. I would start a tmux session. Tmux would set `TERM` to `'screen'`. `vte-2.91.sh` would execute, but because TERM had changed, the script would exit early. `__vte_prompt_command` would *not* be defined.
3. My shell config would execute `PROMPT_COMMAND`, calling `__vte_prompt_command`, which isn't set, hence the error message.

There's clearly some kind of problem with `vte-2.91.sh`. **But I worked around this by configuring tmux to set `TERM` to something vte was expecting:**

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

It's all a bit convoluted, but I suspect a similar explanation in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the corresponding code by editing your `~/.bashrc` by using `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`, searching for the string **"vte"** with STRG+F and outcommenting the line with a `#`.
On my system, the line looked like this, I guess an old installation of Ubuntu Budgie put it there:

```
if [ $TILIX_ID ] || [ $VTE_VERSION ] ; then source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh; fi # Ubuntu Budgie END
```

And if it looks like this, the line in your terminal will not appear anymore:

```
#if [ $TILIX_ID ] || [ $VTE_VERSION ] ; then source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh; fi # Ubuntu Budgie END
```

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS7 (64 bit):

Try installing using `yum` command.

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y terminator
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install -y terminator #again
```

Resart the command prompt terminal, This worked for me (:

Reference: http://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/install-terminator-in-centos-7-64bit

Answer (score 0):

```
set +v
```

I think you may somehow made: `set -v`  (Prints shell input lines as they are read.)

```
so set i
```

Comment: sry the line was cut.  what i mean is just give the command:  set +v